# Storing Arrays Locally (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, save

I want to store text that is typed in a text field inside an array, and then save that string locally on the device so if I were to close the app and reopen it, the strings contents would still be accessible. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Look into using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Only use `NSUserDefaults` if the amount of text is very small (on the order of kilobytes maximum) otherwise look into saving the data on the filesystem and re-loading the data when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store the array on device locally.

//To store

```
var userdefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userdefaults.setObject(yourArray, forKey: anyKey)
userdefaults.synchronize()
```

//To read

```
var myArray : NSArray = userdefaults.objectForKey(anyKey) as NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

// Save array of strings

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(arrayOfString, forKey:"key")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

// get array of strings

```
var arrayOfText : NSArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("key") as! NSArray
```

Comment: What exactly is a "key"? Sorry that may sound like a dumb question to you but I've just started learning Swift

Comment: you can set any key to store object in userdefaults. Using same key you can fetch data from userdefaults